# Prevent printing failed check

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool check(int count[], string race){
  for(int i = 0; i < ('Z' + 1); i++){
   if(count[i]!= 0 && (count[race[0]] != count[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void score(string race){
  int numteams = 0;
  int scores['Z' + 1] = {0};
  int count['Z' + 1] = {0};

  for(int i = 0; i < race.length(); ++i){
    if(scores[race[i]] == 0){
      numteams++;
    }
    scores[race[i]] = i + 1 + scores[race[i]];
    count[race[i]]++;
  }

  if(check(count, race) != true){
    cout << "The teams are not equal, please re-enter your values: ";
    cin >> race;
    score(race);
     
  }
  
  cout << "There are " << numteams << " teams." << endl;
  cout << "There are " << count[race[0]] << " runners on each team." << endl;

  double avg = (scores[race[0]])/(count[race[0]] * 1.0);
  char win = race[0];
  for(int i = 'A'; i < ('Z' + 1); i++){
    if(scores[i]!=0){
      cout << "Average for team " << (char)(i) << " is: " << scores[i]/(count[i] * 1.0) << endl;
      if(avg > (scores[i])/(count[i] * 1.0)){
        avg = (scores[i])/(count[i] * 1.0);
        win = i;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "The winning team is '" << win << "' with a score of " << avg << endl;
  cout << endl;
}



int main() {
  string race;
  cout << "Enter the outcome of the race (in all uppercase letters): ";
  cin >> race;
  while(race != "done"){
    score(race);
    cout << "Enter the outcome of the race (in all uppercase letters): ";
    cin >> race;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The assignment is to have a user input results of a race without knowing how many teams and participants are in the race. I have most of it done and working fine, the only issue is when the string goes through the **check function**. The string fails then once it is corrected it goes through with the rest of the code but **after**, so does the rejected string. How can I make it so the wrong string gets ignored completely?

Answer (score 0):

You first store the string, then do the check.
Do instead the check first and store only if not failed.